# PHP If URL contains only a certain parameter

Tags: php, url, parameters, get

I understand I can use the following to see if the parameter p exists in the URL. However this will also work if there is also a q, t, r etc parameter

> if(isset($_GET['p'])) {}

I also know that the following sees if there is any parameter set

> if(count($_GET)) {}

However what i need is:

If ONLY parameter p exists -> do something... else if parameter p exists and any other parameter exists else do something... else if parameter != p , or no parameter exists - do something else

Any tips would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['p']) && count($_GET['p']) == 1){
//do something
} else if (isset($_GET['p'])){
//do something
} else {
//do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently what you are looking for:

```
<?php
// ...
if ((count($_GET) === 1) && isset($_GET['p'])) {
  // GET argument 'p' exists and is the only one
} elseif (isset($_GET['p']) {
  // GET argument'p' exists
} else{
  // GET argument'p' does _not_ exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$wantedKeys = ['p'];

if (array_diff_key($_GET, array_flip($wantedKeys))) {
    echo 'keys other than ', join(', ', $wantedKeys), ' are in $_GET';
}
```

This scales up to any number of wanted keys.
In combination with "needs all and none other":

```
if (
    count(array_intersect_key($_GET, array_flip($wantedKeys))) == count($wantedKeys)
    && !array_diff_key($_GET, array_flip($wantedKeys))
) {
    echo 'only the keys ', join(', ', $wantedKeys), ' are in $_GET';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution with nested `if`s (which might perform better) :

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['p'])) { # If parameter p exists
    if (count($_GET) == 1) { # If only p exists
        // Do something
    } else { # If other parameters exist
        // Do something else
    }
} else { # If p doesn't exist
    // Do yet something else
}
```